# Qmetry - How to save soap api response to xml file

Tags: web-services, testing, soap, qaf

In Qmetry, I am calling below soap api request.

```
user requests 'post.sample.call'
```

Want to save the response in a xml file  (sample.xml). Save response to "sample.xml"

Is there a step in qmetry to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If purpose to save response for later reference, you will be able to find it under [command log](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf_reporting.html#test-case-tabs) tab in qaf report. If you want to validate response you can utilize methods available with [qaf we service support library](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-ws/wiki). For any other purpose if you want to write response to file use get response from test base and write to file. Below code will give you response to write in file.

```
String responseBody = new RestTestBase().getResponse().getMessageBody();
```